# webpack cannot load image

Tags: cordova, reactjs, webpack

i am creating mobile app using React + Material-ui and use webpack to create bundle to include it in `index.html`. i import image and use it in react 
but image not load and this error appear in console:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

webpack config ;

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: path.join(__dirname, 'www', 'js', 'routing.jsx')
    },
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: filename,
        library: '[name]',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        umdNamedDefine: true,
        publicPath: "/www/js/bundle/"
    },
    node: {fs: "empty"},
    plugins: [],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }, {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            }, {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: "json-loader"
            }, {
                test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg|otf|ttf|eot|woff)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            }
        ],
        noParse: [/dist\/ol\.js/, /dist\/jspdf.debug\.js/]
    }
};
```

image import and usage :

```
import img from '../img/thumbnail .png'
<img src={map.thumbnail_url} onError={(e) => {
                                    e.target.src = {img}
                                }}/>
```

srceenshot:

[image]

Comment: In the documentation they use it like: `var url = require("file-loader!./file.png");`, maybe the **file-loader!** part is required.

Comment: There are two parts to your problem.

First try setting   ```<img src={img} />``` instead of in the error, to check if the image is actually loading up. If it shows the right image, then the problem is settings the e.target.src = {img} which is what I think might be the issue

Comment: image not loading but it appears in output folder @jssridhar

Comment: @Hosar not working

Answer (score -1):

Your import statement `import img from '../img/thumbnail .png'`, there is a space before the file-extension. Try `import img from '../img/thumbnail.png'`

Comment: this is the correct name of file however i changed the name but the same error appear